# EF 6 fetch results with many-to-many relations in c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, many-to-many

Need to fetch linked table data in C#, here is the case

```
public class Book
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<BookCategory> BookCategories { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<BookCategory> BookCategories { get; set; }
}

public class BookCategory
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Book Book { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

Now I need to fetch a List of books with BooksCategories for each book from DB in a single Linq Query with EF 6. Specifically, I need the BookCategories property to be filled up for each Book in the list of Books with the best code.

Can you please suggest the C# code for the same?

Comment: Fisrt of all I would change your joining table

Comment: You don't need both id's property in your joining table, you can just have one ID to identify the object, then after fixing your entity configurations you can substitute your "generic" collections with object specific collections. That means in Book class you will have ````public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }````, whereas in Category class you'll have ````public virtual ICollection<Book> Books{ get; set;}````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load related entities with `Include`. So your LINQ should look something like this

```
using (var context = new EntityContext())
{
    var books = context.Books
       .Include(b => b.BookCategories)
       .ToList();
}
```

You can read more about [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data)